# PHP 7.0 Illegal offset type in isset or empty

Tags: php, wordpress

On my Apache `ErrorLog` file I see many times this warning message:

> [Wed Aug 23 17:27:25.146025 2017] [:error] [pid 14989] [client 66.249.76.54:44935] PHP Warning:  Illegal offset type in isset or empty in /var/www/html/blog/wp-content/plugins/ilab-media-tools/classes/tools/s3/ilab-media-s3-tool.php on line 1012

It's related to a Wordpress plugin, I tried on [Github](https://github.com/Interfacelab/ilab-media-tools/issues/11) to ask help from author (as many others) but nothing.

The warning points to this function:

```
public function imageDownsize($fail,$id,$size) {
    if (apply_filters('ilab_imgix_enabled', false)) {
            return $fail;
    }

    $meta=wp_get_attachment_metadata($id);
    // This is the line of the warning:
    if (!isset($meta['sizes']) || !isset($meta['sizes'][$size])) {
            return $fail;
    }

    $sizeMeta = $meta['sizes'][$size];
    if (!isset($sizeMeta['s3'])) {
            return $fail;
    }

    $url = $sizeMeta['s3']['url'];

    $result=[
            $url,
            $sizeMeta['width'],
            $sizeMeta['height'],
        true
    ];

    return $result;
}
```

Apache prints this warning every minute. **Is there a way to fix this annoying message warning?**

This is the output of `var_dump($meta);`:

```
array(7) {
  ["width"]=&gt;
  int(140)
  ["height"]=&gt;
  int(140)
  ["file"]=&gt;
  string(31) "2016/01/logo_retina.png"
  ["sizes"]=&gt;
  array(0) {
  }
  ["image_meta"]=&gt;
  array(12) {
    ["aperture"]=&gt;
    int(0)
    ["credit"]=&gt;
    string(0) ""
    ["camera"]=&gt;
    string(0) ""
    ["caption"]=&gt;
    string(0) ""
    ["created_timestamp"]=&gt;
    int(0)
    ["copyright"]=&gt;
    string(0) ""
    ["focal_length"]=&gt;
    int(0)
    ["iso"]=&gt;
    int(0)
    ["shutter_speed"]=&gt;
    int(0)
    ["title"]=&gt;
    string(0) ""
    ["orientation"]=&gt;
    int(0)
    ["keywords"]=&gt;
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  ["ewww_image_optimizer"]=&gt;
  string(30) "Reduced by 16.3% (1.3&nbsp;kB)"
  ["s3"]=&gt;
  array(3) {
    ["url"]=&gt;
    string(79) "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/blog-example/2016/01/logo_retina.png"
    ["bucket"]=&gt;
    string(12) "blog-example"
    ["key"]=&gt;
    string(31) "2016/01/logo_retina.png"
  }
}
array(7) {
  ["width"]=&gt;
  int(140)
  ["height"]=&gt;
  int(140)
  ["file"]=&gt;
  string(31) "2016/01/logo_retina.png"
  ["sizes"]=&gt;
  array(0) {
  }
  ["image_meta"]=&gt;
  array(12) {
    ["aperture"]=&gt;
    int(0)
    ["credit"]=&gt;
    string(0) ""
    ["camera"]=&gt;
    string(0) ""
    ["caption"]=&gt;
    string(0) ""
    ["created_timestamp"]=&gt;
    int(0)
    ["copyright"]=&gt;
    string(0) ""
    ["focal_length"]=&gt;
    int(0)
    ["iso"]=&gt;
    int(0)
    ["shutter_speed"]=&gt;
    int(0)
    ["title"]=&gt;
    string(0) ""
    ["orientation"]=&gt;
    int(0)
    ["keywords"]=&gt;
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  ["ewww_image_optimizer"]=&gt;
  string(30) "Reduced by 16.3% (1.3&nbsp;kB)"
  ["s3"]=&gt;
  array(3) {
    ["url"]=&gt;
    string(79) "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/blog-example/2016/01/logo_retina.png"
    ["bucket"]=&gt;
    string(12) "blog-example"
    ["key"]=&gt;
    string(31) "2016/01/logo_retina.png"
  }
}
array(7) {
  ["width"]=&gt;
  int(140)
  ["height"]=&gt;
  int(140)
  ["file"]=&gt;
  string(31) "2016/01/logo_retina.png"
  ["sizes"]=&gt;
  array(0) {
  }
  ["image_meta"]=&gt;
  array(12) {
    ["aperture"]=&gt;
    int(0)
    ["credit"]=&gt;
    string(0) ""
    ["camera"]=&gt;
    string(0) ""
    ["caption"]=&gt;
    string(0) ""
    ["created_timestamp"]=&gt;
    int(0)
    ["copyright"]=&gt;
    string(0) ""
    ["focal_length"]=&gt;
    int(0)
    ["iso"]=&gt;
    int(0)
    ["shutter_speed"]=&gt;
    int(0)
    ["title"]=&gt;
    string(0) ""
    ["orientation"]=&gt;
    int(0)
    ["keywords"]=&gt;
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  ["ewww_image_optimizer"]=&gt;
  string(30) "Reduced by 16.3% (1.3&nbsp;kB)"
  ["s3"]=&gt;
  array(3) {
    ["url"]=&gt;
    string(79) "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/blog-example/2016/01/logo_retina.png"
    ["bucket"]=&gt;
    string(12) "blog-example"
    ["key"]=&gt;
    string(31) "2016/01/logo_retina.png"
  }
}
array(7) {
  ["width"]=&gt;
  int(140)
  ["height"]=&gt;
  int(140)
  ["file"]=&gt;
  string(31) "2016/01/logo_retina.png"
  ["sizes"]=&gt;
  array(0) {
  }
  ["image_meta"]=&gt;
  array(12) {
    ["aperture"]=&gt;
    int(0)
    ["credit"]=&gt;
    string(0) ""
    ["camera"]=&gt;
    string(0) ""
    ["caption"]=&gt;
    string(0) ""
    ["created_timestamp"]=&gt;
    int(0)
    ["copyright"]=&gt;
    string(0) ""
    ["focal_length"]=&gt;
    int(0)
    ["iso"]=&gt;
    int(0)
    ["shutter_speed"]=&gt;
    int(0)
    ["title"]=&gt;
    string(0) ""
    ["orientation"]=&gt;
    int(0)
    ["keywords"]=&gt;
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  ["ewww_image_optimizer"]=&gt;
  string(30) "Reduced by 16.3% (1.3&nbsp;kB)"
  ["s3"]=&gt;
  array(3) {
    ["url"]=&gt;
    string(79) "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/blog-example/2016/01/logo_retina.png"
    ["bucket"]=&gt;
    string(12) "blog-example"
    ["key"]=&gt;
    string(31) "2016/01/logo_retina.png"
  }
}
array(7) {
  ["width"]=&gt;
  int(140)
  ["height"]=&gt;
  int(140)
  ["file"]=&gt;
  string(31) "2016/01/logo_retina.png"
  ["sizes"]=&gt;
  array(0) {
  }
  ["image_meta"]=&gt;
  array(12) {
    ["aperture"]=&gt;
    int(0)
    ["credit"]=&gt;
    string(0) ""
    ["camera"]=&gt;
    string(0) ""
    ["caption"]=&gt;
    string(0) ""
    ["created_timestamp"]=&gt;
    int(0)
    ["copyright"]=&gt;
    string(0) ""
    ["focal_length"]=&gt;
    int(0)
    ["iso"]=&gt;
    int(0)
    ["shutter_speed"]=&gt;
    int(0)
    ["title"]=&gt;
    string(0) ""
    ["orientation"]=&gt;
    int(0)
    ["keywords"]=&gt;
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  ["ewww_image_optimizer"]=&gt;
  string(30) "Reduced by 16.3% (1.3&nbsp;kB)"
  ["s3"]=&gt;
  array(3) {
    ["url"]=&gt;
    string(79) "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/blog-example/2016/01/logo_retina.png"
    ["bucket"]=&gt;
    string(12) "blog-example"
    ["key"]=&gt;
    string(31) "2016/01/logo_retina.png"
  }
}
```

And the output of `var_dump($size);`:

```
string(4) "full"
array(2) {
  [0]=&gt;
  int(32)
  [1]=&gt;
  int(32)
}
array(2) {
  [0]=&gt;
  int(192)
  [1]=&gt;
  int(192)
}
array(2) {
  [0]=&gt;
  int(180)
  [1]=&gt;
  int(180)
}
array(2) {
  [0]=&gt;
  int(270)
  [1]=&gt;
  int(270)
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `$meta` is an array ?

Comment: please try once :
public function imageDownsize($fail,$id,array $size) {


}

Comment: Can you post the result of `var_dump($meta);`

Comment: That's it `["sizes"]=&gt;
  array(0) {
  }`

Comment: Your `sizes` array in your `meta` array has zero elements

Comment: @Hackerman I added the sizes array output

Comment: You can add this line and it should work `if(count($meta["sizes"]) < $size) return $fail;`

Comment: Put that line below this one `$meta=wp_get_attachment_metadata($id);`

Comment: @Hackerman I love you, you found the solution!

Comment: Glad to help @NineCattoRules...I'll make the fix and the pull request on github too.

Comment: According to your `var_dump`, `$size` is an array, which causes the offset error. Also `if(count($meta["sizes"]) < $size) return $fail;` will still return the error when the if condtion is not met. You should check the `$size` you are passing to the function.

Comment: @JungleZombie, Yeah, now that you mention it, the line that I posted shouldn't be the right answer....let me take another look at it

Comment: Yeah, from my perspective, I'm not seeing the point to check or the meaning of the `$size` array, since what you are trying to achieve is, to return this value `$url = $sizeMeta['s3']['url'];` and that value exist in the `$meta` array....what is the meaning of the `$size` array?

Comment: Actually the code doesn't have much sense at all....i'll have to check the code that calls that function too in order to get a better understanding...

Comment: @Hackerman @JungleZombie I found only 1 new error in my log file: `PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'sizes' in /var/www/html/blog/wp-content/                                                                                      plugins/ilab-media-tools/classes/tools/s3/ilab-media-s3-tool.php on line 1012`

Answer (score 0):

So, based on the GitHub issue, it looks like this line is failing somehow

```
$meta=wp_get_attachment_metadata($id);
```

According to the [WP reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_metadata/) it returns

> Attachment meta field. False on failure.

The code mistakenly assumes it's always going to get an array back. So you could fix this by changing the following to make sure `$meta` isn't false

```
if (!$meta || !isset($meta['sizes']) || !isset($meta['sizes'][$size])) {
        return $fail;
}
```

Comment: Ok, do a `var_dump($meta);` and see what it's returning then

Comment: Oh, wait. Try doing a `var_dump($size);` as well. That might be the problem

Comment: The illegal offset type means that the offset (the value inbetween [ ]) is invalid. That is, it's not a string, number, or boolean. If `$size` is an array or an object, it will result in this warning.

Comment: @Hackerman solves my problem with `if(count($meta["sizes"]) < $size) return $fail;`